# R how to use group_by to get averages per group

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the mpg data set, I want to group by displacement (2.0 and 3.1).

- Next sum all the cty of the 2.0 group.
- Lastly in a final column divide the sum above with the sum of all the cty for 2.0 and 3.1.

So far I've only been able do the grouping without error:

```
data(mpg)

mpg2 <- filter(mpg, manufacturer == "audi" & year == 2008 & cyl < 8)

x <- group_by(mpg2, displ) 
    # %>% mutate(total_cty = {sum(.$cty)}) #new column getting the total of cty for each group (2.0, 3.1)
    # proportion = total_cty/total_cty_of.2.0 + total_cty_of.3.1
```

I know group_by alone doesn't change the appearance, except when you use aggregates on it like summarise. I would like to be able to see the new result though if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `$` in `dplyr` pipes, very rarely they are useful. When you use that the groupings are lost.

We can calculate `sum` `cty` for each `displ` value and then calculate their proportion.

```
library(dplyr)

mpg2 %>%
  group_by(displ) %>%
  summarise(cty = sum(cty)) %>%
  mutate(cty_prop = cty/sum(cty))

# displ   cty cty_prop
#  <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
#1   2      80    0.544
#2   3.1    67    0.456
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could use sum in summarise lol, thanks again!!!